# Split string by list of indexes

Tags: python, string, indexing, split

I need a function that splits the string by indexes specified in indexes. Wrong indexes must be ignored.
My code:

```
def split_by_index(s: str, indexes: List[int]) -> List[str]:
    parts = [s[i:j] for i,j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:]+[None])]
    return parts
```

My strings:

```
split_by_index("pythoniscool,isn'tit?", [6, 8, 12, 13, 18])
split_by_index("no luck", [42])
```

Output:

```
['is', 'cool', ',', "isn't", 'it?']
['']
```

Expected output:

```
["python", "is", "cool", ",", "isn't", "it?"]
["no luck"]
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: first appedn from left 0 to your indexes list, rest should be fine     `indexes = [0] + indexes`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the `0`th index, while you are starting from `6:8` in your first example and `42:None` in the second:

```
def split_by_index(s: str, indexes: List[int]) -> List[str]:
    parts = [s[i:j] for i,j in zip([0] + indexes, indexes + [None])]
    return parts
```

Answer (score 0):

the only appending zero to your list would have solved as mentioned in my comment, but for ignoring if the index is bigger you could add the same condition inside for loop

```
def split_by_index(s: str, indexes):
    indexes = [0] + indexes + [None]
    parts = [s[i:j] for i,j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:]) if j and j < len(s)]
    return parts
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found that works for both cases:

```
def split_by_index(s: str, indexes: List[int]) -> List[str]:
    parts = [s[i:j] for i,j in zip([0] + indexes, indexes + [None])]
    if '' in parts:
        parts.pop()
    return parts
```